# Deleting AWS S3 bucket after x number of days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way of automatically deleting an S3 bucket after say 30 days?  I understand I can use the lifecycle to delete the objects inside the bucket.
Or is there a way of automatically deleting a bucket I delete all the objects in it after 30days?

Comment: a lambda is an option?

Comment: Why would you want to delete the bucket? Bucket names are shared across S3. Once you delete it, there might be case where someone else takes your bucket name.

Comment: I want to keep the data around for 30 days after an EC2 instance is deleted just in case I need the data.  After 30 days the data+bucket are no longer required

Comment: Use lifecycle polity and the bucket will not be charged when it is empty.